# codes dont work when upload to hosting site

Tags: html, css, carousel

My carousel is not working when I upload to hosting site but in my pc are 
functional. Like, It will automatically move to next slides. I'm trying another possible solution, but when I upload to hosting site it doesn't work pretty well
Any suggestions about this?

Here's the link of my [site](https://kkeennyy-tan.github.io/index.html).
I hope you can understand what i mean, sorry for my poor english.
Thanks!

```css
#banner{
}
#banner img{
  max-width: 100%; /* para magin responsive xa */    
}
#banner .carousel-indicators {
  bottom: 20px;
}
/* No need individual color class unless you need it multiple times */
#banner{
  color: #000; /* Black */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
#banner .item{
  background: #dfad70;
  padding: 50px 0 70px;    
}
#banner .item:nth-child(1){
  background: #8AC9ED;
}
#banner .item:nth-child(2){
  background: #A3DAD3;
}
#banner .item:nth-child(3){
  background: #BF9CCB;
}
#banner .item:nth-child(4){
  background: #dfad70;
}

#banner h1{
  color: #fff; /* White */
}
#banner ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;    
}
.carousel-inner ul{
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-inner li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f00c";
  padding-right: 20px;   
}
#banner .section-1{
  font-family: buenard;
  font-size: 3em; 
}
#banner .section-2{
  font-family: buenard;
  font-size: 1.5em; 
}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  #banner .item,
  #banner .item .text-right{
    text-align: center;
  }

  #banner ul{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
  }
   #banner .item{ 
     min-height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>GOOD HEART</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/pLO28P8.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/carousel.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner">
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 text-right"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/250/any" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <h1 class="animated fadeInUpBig section-1">ABOUT</h1>
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInUpBig slide-delay-2 section-2">
                                 Makes quality cones and provide service like partners.
                              </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .row -->
                </div>
                <!-- end .item -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 text-right"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/250/any" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <h1 class="animated bounce section-1">Products</h1>
                            <ul class="animated fadeInUpBig slide-delay-2 section-2">
                                <li>Wafer Cones</li>
                                <li>Sugar conesipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                                <li>Bakery Products</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .row -->
                </div>
                <!-- end .item -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 text-right"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/250/any" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <h1 class="animated fadeInDownBig section-2">Recognized Religious Halal Certification and Accreditation Authority</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .row -->
                </div>
                <!-- end .item -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 text-right"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/250/any" /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <h1 class="animated bounce section-1">System Certification</h1>
                            <ul class="animated fadeInUpBig slide-delay-2 section-2">
                                <li>HACCP CODEX ALIMENTARIUS</li>
                                <li>GOOD MANUFACTURING PRACTICE</li>
                                <li>FOOD SAFETY SYSTEM CERTIFICATION 22000</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .row -->
                </div>
                <!-- end .item -->
            </div>
            <!-- end .carousel-inner -->
        </div>
        <!--// end .carousel -->
    </div>
    <!-- end #banner -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not run because of this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Your web is host to HTTPS which is secure chanel, so every source in your web site also have to come from secure chanel. If you open inspection (press F12) on your website and open console log tab, you will see a messages

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://kkeennyy-tan.github.io/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So to solve the problem you just need to change "http://" to "https://"

Comment: Thanks @vtc I already change all http to https both css at js link

Answer (score 1):

Your site is on https but you are referencing external assets as http, this creates a security issue. You dont have the problem on your local webserver because you are accessing it over http.

Always begin external assets url by only //

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If the external assets is available on https, always use `https://`.

Always check out console in developper tools (F11), you can often see whats wrong for yourself.

Comment: does it mean I will remove every https: in my css links? 
like this? https://imgur.com/a/82vTy

Comment: Its protocol relative url, means that the page will try to load external reference with his own protocol. The best practice is to always load over https when it is possible.

Comment: Thanks man it works!... I have already put https in every css and JS and its working now